# Cambiar el connection string en tiempo de ejecucion

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017, entity-framework-6

tengo una cadena una aplicacion hecha en vb.net, esta aplicación la corro en dos o tres redes diferentes, existe alguna manera de que se testee la conexion a una base de datos y si no responde utilice otra cadena??
mi idea es algo asi:
if Conexion1 **no anda**  then 
utilizar Conexion2

utilizo entity Framework para conectarme a las bd.

EDITO PARA Peguntar algo, extendiendo la pregunta original con las respuestas dadas

Encontré un problema con la solución que me dieron primero, y es que no puedo ejecutar el procedimiento antes de la llamada al constructor. Y si implemento la segunda respuesta, debo asegurarme de que en cada llamada el context llame a la función que detecte el connectionString válido.

Existe una manera de chequear el connection string antes de instanciar el dbcontext?!?

Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer sobrecarga del constructor de tu context para mandar la cadena de conexión

```
public class MiDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MiDbContext(string connectionString) 
        : base(connectionString)
    {

    }
}
```

y cuando instancias tu DbContext mandar la cadena que necesitas

```
var context = new MiDbContext("connectionStringCompleta");
```

Solamente el codigo te lo mando en C#, ya que no tengo algun proyecto con esto en VB.NET, pero relativamente es lo mismo.

Comment: hola, creo que no entendiste la pregunta, yo quiero saber si hay alguna manera de saber si una conexion esta andando y si no esta andando, usar otra cadena.

Answer (score 1):

En vb.net la clase *SqlConnection* tiene una propiedad que se llama *State* con la que puedes comprobar si esta abierta o cerrada la conexion.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.state

```
Dim o As New SqlConnection
If o.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
   'la conexion esta cerrada
End If
```

Comment: pense que era la solución pero no. Edite mi pregunta para aclararla